# How to line up images on the same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code below and I've tried every trick in the book to make all the images have the same dimensions and still make it Bootstrap responsive. But it seems like I have to choose one or the other. **So I want to instead line up all the images on one line.**

I've included an image showing what I mean:

[image]

```css
/* Books */

#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.description_one, .description_two, .description_three {
  color: #9B0103;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #9B0103;
  border-top: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.description_one a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

#book_column a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

/* End of Books */
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
      
      <!-- First Book -->
      
      <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1472913234l/29563587.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_one' token_id='4ce0e43b806457bbc21881748d6a50d2'>
                <div class='description_one'>
                  5:05:12
                </div> </a>
            </div>            
                                        

<!-- End of First Book -->

<!-- Second Book -->

  <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1388211242l/69571.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_two' token_id='bb8673cb597c7fc7cba7bc13d9f08a4b'>
                <div class='description_two'>
                  6:32:14
                </div> </a>
            </div>            


<!-- End of Second Book -->

<!-- Third Book -->
  <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1342493368l/3636.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_three' token_id='25ea7f6c20f1f185841ed88c9a9d2f2c'>
                <div class='description_three'>
                  7:12:04
                </div> </a>
            </div>            
                                         
<!-- End of Third Book -->
```

Comment: Setting a height for `book_column` and setting `img` height to 100% should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to make use of `position: absolute` on the divs. The `#book_column` can be set to

```
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
```

which will cause the images to be lined up in one line

Set the parent `#books_div` to `text-align: center` so that the list of books will be displayed in the center of the parent div. Height can be set for #book_column so that all the images take up the same height.

Refer this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9bd1rdcv/1/